# What structure should I have for mocking an embedded systems class for desktop testing?

Tags: c++, cmake, mocking, embedded, googlemock

I am building an embedded application in C++, but I want to test it through conventional continuous integration techniques. I am working on a library that depends on functions of the hardware such as printing, outputting to a pin, reading in analog data, etc.. Lets call the library lib and the hardware functions core(hardware.h). I have a mock class that covers all of these functions(hardware.h). The issue is that when I compile the code for the embedded application I need to include a header file for the hardware definitions, but I want to swap this out for the mock header when I want to do testing. Is there a way to get Cmake to do this? Should I be doing this a different way? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I have made this work in IDE and such, but never with cmake and continuous integration.

```
-Lib
 --src
  ---button.h
  ---button.cpp
 --test
  ---testButton.cpp
-core
 ---hardware.h
-Mock
 ---hardware.h
```

```
//button.h
#include hardware.h
setPinMode(Input);
```

Is there a way to have cmake link the correct hardware.h up to the mock during debugging and the core during release?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.com!  please share your attempted cmake command so that the community can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable plan. I recommend a tweak: Use one hardware.h that abstracts away all of the differences and use two hardware.cpps (or whatever), one for the mock hardware and the other for the real hardware. This way everyone includes the same header and links to the appropriate hardware.cpp for the target. The compiler knows nothing and the linker handles everything. The code atop the hardware abstraction gets to remain identical. This makes the testing performed on the mock more likely to be valid for the real target.

Comment: Thanks very much for your Idea! That would certainly work, but I am not sure I understand how to implement it. In the header file you would define some conditions that test for a unit test build and add in the appropriate header file?

Answer (score 1):

We deal with this normally in the following way:

```
--lib
 ---hardware_interface.h
 ---etc
--MCU_TYPE
 ---main.cpp
 ---hardware_mcu_type.h
 ---hardware_mcu_type.cpp
--test
 ---main.cpp
 ---hardware_mock.h
```

As you can see we have a generic folder with common code. All code in the library uses the interface class from `hardware_interface.h` (we often have multiple interfaces for I2C, SPI, UART etc. all defined in separate files). All classes making use a specific interface have a function to set a pointer or reference to the interface. This is done in the main.cpp files.

Now these interfaces are pure virtual. When building an application it is thus required to fill these in. This is where either `hardware_mcu_type.h` or `hardware_mock.h` come in. In the main for the actual mcu the actual hardware implementations are used. When testing on a pc the mock objects are used.

You do need at least a switch in the `CMakeLists.txt` file building the different files for different builds.

*Side note*: please not that memory access and allocation is difficult to test on a different platform as this may vary. The unit tests are best focused on testing logic.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a macro "MOCK_TEST", which when defined causes your mock code to get compiled, and when its not defined causes your embedded Hardware Abstraction Layer to be compiled. This way you can selectively compile mock/HAL.

```
//------ hardware.cpp ------
#ifdef MOCK_TEST
<Mock code>
#elif
<HAL code>
#endif
```

Pass this macro using the compiler option -D (in gcc) while compiling the mock.

```
$CC -c -DMOCK_TEST hardware.cpp (for compiling mock)
```

Integrate these changes for the two targets you are defining in CMake.

Comment: Thanks very much for your idea! If I understand correctly this would work, but requires that I integrate the mock libraries and the HAL libraries. I think that might be too much for me to maintain.

Comment: Ok i missed the detail that mock and hal are libraries, and not just object files. If mock and HAL are two separate libraries offering the same set of APIs (the same header file), then it should be pretty easier than this. At link time, check if MOCK_TEST macro is defined. If so, link in the mock library, otherwise link the HAL library. Similarly compile the libraries depending on this macro.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do! Any chance you can post a short cmake example?

Comment: It is pretty easy to do in Makefile. Need to see how it can be done in CMake.